# Error Java Script converting URL into saved URL

Tags: javascript

I have anchor link in my page. When I clicked on page anchor link converted into saved url.
Say ex

```
<a href="/our-work/home" > Home <a>
```

When I click on above link, that converted into

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" savedurl="/our-work/home"> Home <a>
```

So I dont want this changed url. my URL should be original[normal achorlink].

Comment: Your question is not very clear, please try to tell us what you want to do, and show some code that you have tried.

Comment: Use code notation - the `{}` button - when posting code.

Comment: Why do you invent your own attribute?

Comment: HTML5 allows you to add custom attributes to any HTML tag using the prefix `data-`. [Here](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) are some examples.

Comment: my project is sub part of main project. so header and footers are not under my control. some extra Java Script files are gonna add into my project. so i tried to filter those files but there were large amount of files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
<a href="/our-work/home" onclick="changeURL(this)" > Home <a>

function changeURL(ele) {

    var ele_src = $(ele).attr("href");
    $(ele).attr("href",'javascript:void(0)');
    $(ele).attr("savedurl",ele_src);
//    $(ele).removeAttr("onclick"); // if you want to remove after changing href of element.
}
```

Comment: hey thanks JDev. I need the reverse your answer. I dont want rewriting  URL. some script is doing this. so i want to stop this action

Answer (score 0):

The script probably installs a click handler. When using jQuery, you need to write a query to locate the link and run:

```
$(ele).removeAttr("onclick");
```

If you don't use jQuery, use DOM navigation to locate the link and use:

```
ele.onclick = null;
```